# Objects boole / intersection in THREE.JS

Tags: three.js, intersection

How can I cut geometry from geometry in THREE.JS?

How can I cut geometry from groups of geometry?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a library called [ThreeCSG](https://github.com/chandlerprall/ThreeCSG) (stands for "constructive solid geometry") that can do exactly that.

But you should be aware that these kinds of operations are immensely computationally expensive to do, so you might want to look for something different if you plan to update the geometry on every frame. For a simple case like shown in the picture it shouldn't be too complicated to find a shortcut and doing it manually.

Comment: This library is hard work at OBJ elements in THREE.JS